# Main flaw when training linear regression to predict site traffic

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, multiple-regression

This multiple choice question was asked at an exam.

> You are building a multiple linear regression model to predict hourly traffic for government websites. You have access to a large set of features, which include, but are not limited to, the number of pages per site and sets of keywords used per site. Your available web traffic data spans one week. Which of the following describes the MAIN flaw with trying to build such a model given the aforementioned resources?

> A. The traffic data may be uncorrelated to the available features

> B. The traffic data may exhibit daily and weekly patterns

> C. The traffic data may be noisy

> D. The available features may be correlated

> E. None of the above describes a flaw in trying to build such a model

Answer E can be safely discarded. Answer C is true for most data, hence not relevant. I have a hard time deciding between A, B, D.

Assuming A, the features are useless and the model will not learn anything.

D sounds like multicollinearity which is a well-known problem in linear regression (but one that can be addressed).

I don't know what to think of B. I'd probably go with Answer A. Does this make sense ?

Comment: "Uncorrelated" is not a flaw *per se:* it would just be an unfortunate fact waiting to be discovered.  Think again about what "prediction" entails and the extent to which the variables you have are related to it.  How would you use them, for instance, to predict early Sunday morning traffic compared to mid-Wednesday traffic?